# XMLHttpRequest can have arguments?

Tags: javascript

While searching for a way to resolve my problems with CORS, I saw that many examples suggested to put an object, with the property "mozSystem" set to true, inside the constructor of XMLHttpRequest in order to make requests without having problems with the same origin policy.

I have tried it but it doesn't work.

I have a web application in one computer and a https server with a not verified certificate in a different computer to which I send requests in order to fill tables on my web application. 
I send requests to my server in order to get an array of objects in the form of a json but since the request is not sent with the same origin, it fails.
I have tried to put an object with the property "mozSystem" set to true in the constructor for XMLHttpRequest but my IDE tells me that the constructor doesn't take arguments but in the examples I saw, that object is put as an argument of the constructor.
And when I leave the object as an argument and then debug the code, it shows that the property "mozSystem" is false, so it means it didn't work.

Here is an example of how I retrieve the array from the server:

```
var array=[];
function getArray(){
var request= new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(request.readyState===4&&request.status===200){
            array=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        }
    };
request.open('GET',urlOfTheServer,false);
request.send(null);
}
```

So I need to know if putting that object in the constructor makes any difference or if there is any other way to not get errors from the same origin policy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052670/executing-a-script-via-ajax-on-firefox-os-device

Comment: Are you working on Firefox OS project?  `mozSystem` is not applicable to "normal" web apps.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko No, my web app is a "normal" web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/XMLHttpRequest):

> Firefox 16 added a non-standard parameter to the constructor

Your IDE says it doesn't take arguments because the standard implementation of **doesn't**.

`mozSystem` is only used in "privileged applications" which are an obsolete way of installing applications which run in a web browser.

---

You **cannot** use client-side JavaScript to make a browser ignore trust issues with a certificate.

They can only be resolved by:

- Replacing the certificate with one that doesn't have those trust issues
- The user of the browser visiting a URL (as the main URL for the viewport, not one loaded via (for example) XMLHttpRequest) and clicking through the series of warning screens to dismiss it
- The user of the browser / administrator of the computer installing appropriate certificates on the computer so that the trust issues are resolved locally instead of globally

Comment: Alright, then I'll have to go through the warning screens while the certificate has trust issues. Now I'm surprised that there are people who recommend to use that non-standard "solution" with mozSystem but anyway, thank you!